# Best way to create a sitesearch in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, search

Which is the best way to create a site search engine for a dynamic asp.net site with hundreds of dynamic pages. I have seen many products and articles

http://www.karamasoft.com/UltimateSearch/overview.aspx

http://www.sitesearchasp.net

http://www.easysearchasp.net/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163355.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/indexserver.aspx

Comment: You say that you have seen the above links but you haven't mentioned what your take is on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priyan,

Another high-quality open-source option would be the .NET port of Lucene

- [CodeProject - Introducing Lucene](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx)
- [dotlucene](http://www.dotlucene.net)
- [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net)

You haven't mentioned Google's [SiteSearch](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) "product". Is one of your requirements that you'd like to host the search engine/catalog yourself?

Microsoft also has a product [Search Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/serverproducts/searchserverexpress/default.aspx) although I'm not sure if you can install it on any hosting provider.

And (disclaimer: I am the author) there is also a *very basic* open source project on [CodeProject called Searcharoo](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo_7.aspx) (also at [searcharoo.net](http://searcharoo.net)). It is really meant as a 'demonstration/learning experience' - hence the six *how to* articles - but it might suffice for a small dynamic site.

I have used SQL Server Full Text Search for some projects - works well but it's really just searching **database content**, not a combination of static and dynamic Html/Pdf/Word/Jpg etc documents which a "real" web crawler will do.